# count duplicate Files

Tags: python, count, duplicates

I'm new to Python and want to count contents in 60k text files which are the same, and list all the different contents with a number of how many are the same, something like `uniq -c` but on a file, rather than line, level.

So far, I have:

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

mypath = "C:\Users\daniel.schneider\Downloads\Support"  # my Filepath
onlyfiles = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]

for currentFile in onlyfiles:
    currentPath = mypath + '\\' + currentFile
    f = open(currentPath)
    print currentPath
    for currentLine in currentFile:
        print currentLine[24:]      
    f.close()
    break
```

Comment: I would suggest you calculate a hash code for the content of each file, then you can compare the hash codes to find out which files are the same, or use a Python `set()` to find out which are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it thoroughly, but you could use Python's `hashlib` to get a MD5 hash on each file, and store the filenames in a `list` associated with each hash in a dictionary.

Then, to get the unique content with a count of how many files it appears in, iterate over the dictionary:

```
import os
import hashlib

mypath = 'testdup'
onlyfiles = [f for f in os.listdir(mypath)
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(mypath,f)) ]

files = {}
for filename in onlyfiles:
    filehash = hashlib.md5(open(os.path.join(mypath, filename), 'rb')
                              .read()).hexdigest()
    try:
        files[filehash].append(filename)
    except KeyError:
        files[filehash] = [filename]

for filehash, filenames in files.items():
    print('{0} files have this content:'.format(len(filenames)))
    print(open(os.path.join(mypath,filenames[0])).read())
```